# Icalendar date issue

Tags: c#, icalendar

I have used Icalendar in my project, I am facing a weird issue for recurrence request. I am passing DTSTART 28 march but calendar is generated for 29 march. recurrence is untill 30th march. My icalendar is as follow

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Team Test
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Kolkata
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
TZNAME:IST
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160328T223000Z
DTSTAMP:20160321T140058Z
DTEND:20160328T230000Z
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20160330T173000Z
LOCATION:  
UID:request180107lvis.support@mycompanydomain.com
DESCRIPTION:Requester : Yadav, Chandikumar +() +919876543210
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:Requester : Yadav, Chandikumar +() +919876543210

SUMMARY:Conference Testing
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:test.support@mycompanydomain.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN="";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:chandikumar.yadav@mycompanydomain.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN="";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:jatin.kolhe@mycompanydomain.com
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN="Testing":mailto:test.lvis.support@mycompanydomain.com
ATTACH;FMTTYPE=message/rfc822:D:\Projects\abc.pdf
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I have passed DTSTART, DTEND and UNTIL. Unable to figure out where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified:

```
20160328T223000Z
```

Based on the rest of the iCalendar document, I'm guessing you are actually in this timezone:

```
Asia/Kolkata
```

Since that is UTC+5:30, I'm guessing the newly generated time is:

```
2016-03-29 04:00:00 in your own timezone
```

If you want to specify the time in your timezone currenctly, make sure you add `TZID` to all your `DATE-TIME` fields, such as `DTSTART` and don't include the `Z` at the end of the timestamp. (`Z` stands for Zulu time, which is UTC)

Comment: thanks for your reply. but my timezone is same as what i have passed i.e. Asia/Kolkat and when portion in my calendar invite is :-    "When: Occurs every day effective 3/29/2016 until 3/30/2016 from 10:30 PM to 11:00 PM Asia/Kolkata."

Comment: @Chandikumar this is my point exactly. You specified it wrong. Please re-read my answer. You specified the time as UTC

Comment: It actually doesn't. If you only remove the `Z` you specify the time as floating time. It might solve your problem right now, but it might cause new problems later. If somebody processes your event and their computer is in a different timezone, it will just adopt that timezone.

Comment: ok, but i am passing the BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Kolkata, i checked invite time on asia/kolkata timezone and brusseles/paris timezone on my machine, time conversion was correct.

Comment: That timezone block is 100% ignored if you don't also use it in `TZID` parameters on `DTSTART` and such. I think at this point you should just read the actual iCalendar specification, it makes a lot more sense than me talking you through it step by step. It's RFC5545